# How can I get a list of all locations and hometowns used by Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When I access the Facebook Graph API and find a location, I get something like this:

```
"location": {
    "id": 108131085886116,
    "name": "Saint Petersburg, Russia"
},
```

Each location has its own ID. Is there a way I can get a list of all locations that Facebook knows about? Where can I download it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't get a complete list - but depending on your use-case you could just slowly build one out as you encounter new values in your app users' profiles.

You can also [search](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/#searching) for places by name and location as a core part of the API